# How to include double quotes in call parameters values

Tags: karate

I want to pass a parameter value in call function (Background) that includes double quotes. My call is: 
`Background:
 * def userCreated = call read('classpath:create-user.feature') { name: '#(name)'}`

So the call will be {"name": "the name is "Peter""}
I have tried the following:

1. Defining name in karate.config as: name: 'the name is "Peter"', and then call read('classpath:create-user.feature') { name: '#(name)'} - result: {"name": "the name is \"Peter\""}
2. Defining name in karate.config as: name: 'the name is \"Peter\"', , and then call read('classpath:create-user.feature') { name: '#(name)'} -> result: {"name": "the name is \"Peter\""}
3. Including the name value in he call as: call read('classpath:create-user.feature') { name: 'the name is "Peter"'} -> result: {"name": "the name is \"Peter\""}
4. Including the name value in he call as: call read('classpath:create-user.feature') { name: 'the name is \"Peter\"'} -> result: {"name": "the name is \"Peter\""}
5. Defining a string before (Background): * string nameString = 'the name is "Peter"' and then call read('classpath:create-user.feature') { name: '#(nameString)'} -> same result as previous ones.
6. Defining a string before (Background): * string nameString = 'the name is \"Peter\"' and then call read('classpath:create-user.feature') { name: '#(nameString)'} -> same result as previous ones.

I've also checked https://github.com/intuit/karate#type-conversion, but I dont know how to define or include a string as a parameter in call function that includes double quotes.
Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is correct behavior only, inorder to keep your string as a value in JSON that contains `"` it has to be escaped properly.

for escaping `\` will be used before `"`

It doesn't changes anything

```
* def name = ' karate is created by "Peter".'
 # karate is created by "Peter".
* def callInput = {"name" : "#(name)"}
# {"name" : "karate is created by \"Peter\"."}
* print callInput.name
# karate is created by "Peter".
* match callInput.name == name
```

Its all same outside, only inside JSON it will be escaped for String quotes.